# How to set up a local server for iQmol on macOS?

Tags: software, visualization-software, q-chem, iqmol, apple-operating-system

I'm trying to set up iQmol as a tool to submit calculations to Q-Chem on our lab machines to make access to it easier for OChem students. Unfortunately, it is not working properly "from the box".

By default, when one creates a local server in iQmol it uses the csh shell environment and it looks like I only need to adjust Q-Chem environment:
[image: local_server_settings]

These settings nicely work for HF calculations, but when I try to use DFT I have a significant issue: SP or Optimization calculations go fine, but when Frequency calculation is added as a job, the calculation fails at the step `"Calculating analytic Hessian of the SCF energy".`

In the case of H<sub>2</sub> molecule I stops like this:
`Polarizability Matrix (a.u.)`
            `1           2           3`
    `1   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000`
    `2   0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000`
    `3   0.0000000   0.0000000  -6.3752744`
 `Calculating analytic Hessian of the SCF energy`

It also gives an error message:
[image: error_message]
and the scratch folder for the job is not cleared after the job.

The input file is not the issue, as the same file can be submitted using the terminal and the calculation finishes successfully. It does not seem to be a memory issue, as specification of MEM_TOTAL and MEM_STATIC does not solve the problem. I thought that there might be a problem in server settings, but I can't figure out what exactly happened.

I will very much appreciate any suggestion and advice!

Comment: As someone who uses a Mac and Q-Chem (although admittedly not together) this seems strange. I'd contact Q-Chem tech support for help tracking this down. Is there an error message when the "Calculating analytic Hessian" step stops?

Comment: Q-Chem readdressed the question to iQmol, but they did not respond since November... I was hoping someone faced something similar, but succeeded.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison, it seems that there is no error message in the output files, more like job just suddenly terminated. iQmol gives a message: "Job failed to finish".

Comment: Hi @DmitryEremin I just noticed that you are using -nt to do a Frequency calculation. Only use -np to do frequency calculations. If this works, I can make this an answer.

Comment: @CodyAldaz, unfortunately with -np it still fails at the same point. Frequency calculation even cannot run when no -nt or -np are specified (so just one core is used). I still just cannot understand what is going on with this?!

Comment: Dang, that is not good. what is "Job Limit"?

Comment: @CodyAldaz - 1024. Do you mean the value which is set in the bottom of the server configuration window (as on the picture)?
I also reconfigured the server to bash shell, and the problem is still there, just the same.

Comment: Does it give an error message or just stop running? Can you increase the verbosity of the QChem output?

Comment: I'm sorry for being late I the response to @Tyberius comment and not logging in sooner. Our Lab has been in a set-up process for back to research operations where I partially am responsible for things. I'll provide an answer asap!

Comment: @Tyberius, I'll edit the question to expand the answer

Comment: @DmitryEremin Its no problem, Nike is just trying to make sure our site stats look nice, as we are coming up on the 90 day evaluation of public beta. Have you tried other molecules besides H2 and they all fail after the polarizability? If that's the case, its probably beyond anything we can help you with and might just be bug with your setup. If you have only tried H2, is it possible the job time is too low so that energy and optimization can finish, but frequency is just a bit too long. I know in Gaussian it prints the polarizability near the end of the log, well after finishing the freq part

Comment: @DmitryEremin, thanks for coming back! Nice to see you :) The question can stay open.

Comment: @Tyberius I tried for benzyl azide and couple of more. It is just exactly the same and always stops at the same moment. I also tried it on two different machines and tested several functionals and several basis sets. Interesting fact that it is with either bash shell or csh shell and under two different releases of macOS: High Sierra and Catalina. Makes me cry...

Comment: By the way there's now a Q-Chem room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109797/q-chem Can you enter it at least once and say "hello" ?

Comment: @DmitryEremin it seems that on [19 May 2020 you told us](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/879/how-to-set-up-a-local-server-for-iqmol-on-macos#comment904_879) that the Q-Chem support team re-directed you to the iQmol team (i.e. Andrew Gilbert). However Andrew Gilbert's [webpage](http://rsc.anu.edu.au/~agilbert/gilbertspace) that was referred to on the iQmol website and Peter Gill's website, is no longer up. There seems to be no way to contact him without joining research gate: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Andrew-Gilbert-16. Did you try to find out how to ask iqmol Qs?

Comment: @NikeDattani, this very problem still persists, but I indeed was in touch with Andrew Gilbert. One possible way is Q-Chem talk forum, as I think I saw iQmol questions there. The other option is iQmol [bug tracking system](http://iqmol.org/bugtracking/login_page.php?return=%2Fbugtracking%2Fmy_view_page.php)

Answer (score 4):

I do not think the server setup is the problem *per se*.  By default, IQmol is setup to submit jobs to a server that is owned by Q-Chem and those jobs are time-limited at 5-10 min.  (The precise limit has varied over time.)  The `job failed to finish` error reflects this limit.

That said, I am a bit surprised that $\ce{H2}$ frequencies failed to finish. Is it possible that you are either:

- (a) using a large basis set, or
- (b) using a functional that lacks analytic 2nd derivatives, thus defaulting to finite-difference frequencies?  I tried this just now and was successfully able to compute frequencies for $\ce{H2}$ at the B3LYP/6-31G level in a few seconds, well under the time limit.

In any case, the free IQmol server is intended primarily for demonstration purposes and for longer jobs you would need to purchase a Q-Chem license.  IQmol can then be configured to submit jobs to local hardware.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I agree the Q-Chem servers are the whole different story and they are limited to 10 minutes. However the problem I encounter is about server on a local machine. As Andrew Gilbert said "This shouldn’t be a problem, but IQmol was tripping up when it was looking for the pid." After playing for a while with .bashrc and environment settings I was able to run frequency calculations from iQmol for CO, H2O and CO2. However calculation still fails for larger systems even with very small basis set. Same calculations submitted to QChem from terminal works with no issues.